# How can I load my mongoose db before any routing occurs in my express app?

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose

My index template is loading without any mongoose data. But every 
page later looks fine. It has something to do with mongoose loading too late/my routes firing too fast. How can I control this?

https://github.com/MartinMars100/search-1

Comment: I don't see the test folder in your project.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty straight-forward.  Here is the code you use to connect to the database.  You are currently setting up express in parallel.  Move all of that code to the place where I put the comment "put your express stuff here", and it will happen after mongo gets initialized.

```
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI || 'mongodb://localhost/search-therapy', { useMongoClient: true }, function(err) {
  if(err) {
    console.log('Failed connecting to Mongodb');
    // var app = express();
  } else {
    console.log('Successfully connected to Mongo');
    // put your express stuff here
  }
});
```

Comment: Yes, that's the idea.  If you don't want the express routes set up before mongo is connected, you move that code to where it will run after.

Comment: I.e. there's nothing magic about when you call "app.get()" to register a route. It can be at time 0, time 100, time 1000000....

Comment: Hi Jim, I tried your suggestion and did not see any difference.

Comment: That would be because you are doing your require('./routes/index') at time 0.

Comment: I assume this is a race condition.  If you wait a few seconds before you refresh your browser, does it work?

Comment: There are lots of ways to structure this so it will work.  You can also, instead of using require to load your index routes, have index.js export a router and do app.use() in your app.js after mongo loads.  Either way, you need to not register your routes before mongo loads or this will happen.

Comment: I figured it out today. it seems I changed the name of my local db and so I couldn't see the data because there was no data. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should connect to mongoose before requiring express app.
Besides you can create class (if you use es6) for your express app, create init method that would connect your routes. So you can call this method after mongoose connection.